# .NET C#: How to handle forms authentication expiration during an AJAX call

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ajax, timeout, forms-authentication

For context, I have a forms authentication timeout value set in my web.config, and am using ASP.NET MVC 1. I think it might be easiest to state my problem as 2 use cases -- the first one what happens without an authentication timeout, and the second one what happens with an authentication timeout:

**Normal case:**

The user logs into the app, and the authentication timer starts ticking. While the authentication period is still valid, the user clicks something on the page that triggers an AJAX call (through jQuery). We hit the server, process the request, and return a partial view to the user (as an `ActionResult`). The html comes through as a string to the ajax's success method, and I take this html and inject it into a div on the page. This is all expected.

**Timed out case:**

The user logs into the app, and the authentication timer starts ticking. After *x* amount of time, the authentication period expires. With the expiration time up, the user clicks something on the page that triggers an AJAX call (using jQuery). We hit the server, but the authentication ticket is expired. .NET automatically redirects to the `loginURL` value defined in the same web.config element that sets the timeout period. For me, this page is the login page where the user is asked to input username/password to log in. So the `Home/Login` Controller action runs, and eventually returns a full (not partial) view back as a string of html to the ajax's success method. This causes the page to bomb because I'm trying to take a full page's html (with `<html>` tags and all) and inject it into a div on the page.

So therein lies my problem. When the authentication period has expired, and .NET redirects me to the login page, I end up returning a full page's html to an ajax success method. Of course, everything works fine when the server hit isn't an AJAX call -- it redirects fine to the login page. But how can I handle this case? Does anyone have any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so the Account/Login action get's executed when the ticket expires

```
public Action Login()
{
   if(Request.IsAjaxRequest())
   return Content(@"<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1" />");
   //if it is ajax request the div will be filled with this meta tag which will refresh the page


  return View();
}
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. Unfortunately, by the time .NET redirects to the login page, Request.IsAjaxRequest() returns false. Perhaps a new request is generated when .NET realizes the authentication has timed out and decides to hit the `loginURL`.

Comment: @Mega Matt that's probably because you're using mvc1. All AJAX calls made by jQuery will have a header added to indicate it is AJAX. The header to check is X-Requested-With, and the value will be XMLHttpRequest when it is an AJAX call. Try debugging and look for Request.Headers["X-Requested-With"]

Comment: I don't have "X-Requested-With" in Request.Headers. I have "Connection", "Keep-Alive", "Accept", "Accept-Charset", "Accept-Encoding", "Accept-Language", "Cookie", "Host", "Referrer", and "User-Agent". Honestly, I didn't expect to see a header related to AJAX requests if Request.IsAjaxRequest() was returning false. I guess this could still be related to me using MVC 1?

Comment: @Mega Matt atm I'm thinking either mvc 1 or version of jQuery

Comment: Omu, definitely a "feature" of MVC 1. I had a coworker try out the same thing when using MVC 2 and `true` is returned from IsAjaxRequest. I'll have to upgrade. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
 public class BasicAuthenticationAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute, IAuthenticationFilter
{
    public void OnAuthentication(AuthenticationContext filterContext)
    {
        var user = filterContext.HttpContext.User;
        if (user == null || !user.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            if (filterContext.HttpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest())
            {
                filterContext.Result = new JsonResult
                {
                    JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet,
                    Data = new { redirectTo = FormsAuthentication.LoginUrl }
                };
            }
            else
            {
                filterContext.Result = new HttpUnauthorizedResult();
            }
        }
    }
    public void OnAuthenticationChallenge(AuthenticationChallengeContext filterContext)
    {
        //  throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

and then you can use in following way

```
$.get('/foo', function(result) {
if (result.redirectTo) {
    window.location.href = result.redirectTo;
} else {
    // standard stuff
}
```

});