# How to proceed with authentication on ajax requests in asp.net mvc + Forms authentication

Tags: authentication, asp.net-mvc-4, authorize-attribute

i am new to MVC4. i am using ASP.net forms authentication. in all page loads i am able to handle authentication and authorization.

i am using Ajax requests in case of Partial views and to return a object.

in case of partial views i am able to find manage by checking Ajaxrequest by following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4764528/net-c-how-to-handle-forms-authentication-expiration-during-an-ajax-call)

in case of object return how to handle authentication for all ajax requests?

My end goal is to intimate that your session time out or at least to redirect to login page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take a look at [Prevent Forms Authentication Login Page Redirect When You Don’t Want It](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/10/04/prevent-forms-authentication-login-page-redirect-when-you-donrsquot-want.aspx) by Phil Haack

Answer (score 0):

Decorate your action methods with `[Authorize]` attribute.

Comment: i am using [Authorize] by that i am redirecting to login action also. my goal is the users page should be reload or to be intimate that your session time out.